# Is it possible to publish iOS app update after removing Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode7, watchkit, apple-watch

We published an iOS app. In version 6.0, we also included an Apple Watch app. Now, for some reasons, we don't want to offer the Apple Watch app in version 7.0. Will Apple allow this?

Technically, I will remove the WatchKit extenstion and WatchKit app from my app and then I will archive for publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had Apple Watch users, you may get some bad reviews for dropping support, but Apple will allow you to submit an iOS app update that no longer supports the Apple Watch.

Anyone who upgrades to version 7 of your app will have their existing watch app disappear.